# Same number keeps being generated

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

When I try to generate a new random int each time to fill the array it just gives me back the same number. The seed won't change. I'm sure there is an easy answer but I have been looking at it for a few hours and just can't see it.

```
internal class LingoCard  :  ILingoCard
    {
        private ICardNumber[,] _cardNumber;
        private int _teller;
        private int _oddTeller;
        private int rand;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        public LingoCard(bool useEvenNumbers)
        {

            ICardNumber[,] cardNumber = new ICardNumber[5,5];
            _cardNumber = cardNumber;
            if (useEvenNumbers == true)
            {
                UseEvenNumbers(_cardNumber);
            } else {
                UseOddNumbers(_cardNumber);
            }
          
        }
        

        public void UseEvenNumbers(ICardNumber[,] cardNumber)
        {
            while (_teller < 70)
            {
                for (int g = 0; g < 1; g++)
                {
                    rand = rnd.Next(0, 70);
                    CardNumber _walue = new CardNumber(rand);
                    if (rand % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < cardNumber.GetLength(0); i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < cardNumber.GetLength(1); j++)
                            {
                                _cardNumber[i, j] = _walue;
                            }
                            _teller++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @JohnG I created it to check if maybe if I were to put the rand.rnd.Next() in it, it would work. It didnt and I forgot to take it out

Comment: You are going to learn the concept of a shuffle real soon - random doesnt mean unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your random number is the same for all the card numbers is because you're generating one Random number before the two nested for loops and using it to fill in every card number

```
rand = rnd.Next(0, 70); // Random number generated once here
                    CardNumber _walue = new CardNumber(rand);
                    if (rand % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < cardNumber.GetLength(0); i++)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < cardNumber.GetLength(1); j++)
                            {
                                _cardNumber[i, j] = _walue; // same random value assigned for every card number here
                            }
                            _teller++;
                        }
                    }
```

In order to fix it you'd need to generate the random number inside the for loop when you are assigning _cardNumber

```
for (int i = 0; i < cardNumber.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < cardNumber.GetLength(1); j++)
                        {
                            rand = rnd.Next(0, 70) * 2; // Multiply by 2 so the random number is even
                            CardNumber _walue = new CardNumber(rand);
                            _cardNumber[i, j] = _walue;
                        }

                        _teller++;
                    }
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much now all I need is to generate a different number eachtime but im sure I can fix that myself. Thanks to Jeremy Farmer